# Вывод записей по алфавиту php

Tags: php

День добрый, дружное сообщество.
Есть у меня один тривиальный вопрос, решил на всякий случай уточнить у вас, чтоб сделать, как говорится, один раз и хорошо.
Есть сайт, на сайте есть меню. Меню представляет собой огромное кол-во ссылок на разные разделы и просто страницы. На данный момент это хаус и жуть, так как все выводится вместе и без сортировки.
Я хочу все это причесать т.е. разбить по алфавиту по принципу Буква-> по ней пункты начинающиеся на это букву. В принципе для себя я прикинул варианты как это можно реализовать, но решил на всякий случай посоветоваться. Меня интересует не конечный код, а сам алгоритм или принцип кому как сподручней.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: array_sort?  
select * from db order by string asc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Конечный алгоритм выдал уже thunder.

Если принцип:
для линейного меню - уже все готово.

Для вложенного, используйте рекурсивную функцию:

```
if(is_array($item)){
  r_sort($item);
}
```

В идеале, да, все отсортировать на этапе вывода из БД

Comment: Понял, в принципе так и предполагал. Все спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас ссылки выводятся из БД, то можно, например, так:

```
"SELECT вашассылка FROM ссылки ORDER BY названиессылок"
```